# Store does not have a valid Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I can't get my head around it

**actions.js**

```
export const UPDATE = "UPDATE";
```

**utils.js**

```
export default function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
    return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
            return handlers[action.type](state, action)
        } else {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import createReducer from "../../lib/utils.js";
import * as actions from "./actions.js";

export const filter = createReducer({}, {

});
```

**combinedReducers.js**

```
import { 
    combineReducers
} from "redux";
import filter from "../container/filter/reducer.js";

export default combineReducers(Object.assign(
    filter,
));
```

And thats where I try to hook up the `store`.

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from "react-native";
import { 
  Provider 
} from "react-redux";
import { 
  createStore, 
  applyMiddleware, 
  compose,
} from "redux";
import {
  createLogger,
} from "redux-logger";
import reducer from "./src/lib/reducers.js";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import App from "./src/config/App.js"

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({ predicate: (getState, action) => __DEV__});

function configureStore(initialState) {
  const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware,
      loggerMiddleware,
    ),
  );
  return createStore(reducer, initialState, enhancer);
}

const store = configureStore({});

const HelloWorld = () => {
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent("...", () => HelloWorld);
```

And I always get:

> Store does not have a valid reducer
>   Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

What am I doing wrong here? I assume its the `createReducer()` function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
export default combineReducers(Object.assign(
    filter,
));
```

`filter` returns a function and `Object.assign` is returning that function, and `combineReducers` expects an object which every key is a reducer.

So your code should be like this:

```
export default combineReducers(Object.assign({ filter } ));
```

or

```
export default combineReducers({ filter });
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in

```
export default combineReducers(Object.assign, {
    filter,
});
```

because `Object.assign` has no arguments.

Comment: You are right. But if I write it like this `export default combineReducers(Object.assign(
    filter,
));` I still get the error.

Comment: There is another typo in what you just wrote in your comment. Do you mean `export default combineReducers(Object.assign( filter, {} ));` ? `Object.assign` takes two objects as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my reducer broken down

```
//reducers/index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import MyReducer from "./MyReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({    
myProp: MyReducer
});

export default rootReducer;


//reducer/MyReducer.js
export default function MyReducer (state = null, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
         case 'MY_ACTION_TYPE':
           return action.payload
     }
     return state;
 }
```